# count the occurences of each value inside a tuple in Python

Tags: python, count, tuples

Hey guys I have a tuple which looks like this:

```
('NN', 'NNP', '(', 'NN', ')')
```

And I want to count each value of the tuple and return:

```
(('NN', 2), ('NNP', 1), ('(', 1), (')', 1))
```

Any help or guide would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Use a `Counter`, `collections.Counter(t)`

Comment: I did it returns me all the tuple and it counts like 1 occurency:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and construct a `tuple` from its `items`:

```
from collections import Counter
t = ('NN', 'NNP', '(', 'NN', ')')

tuple(Counter(t).items())
# (('NN', 2), ('NNP', 1), ('(', 1), (')', 1))
```

Comment: It works if I want to use it on a tuple but when I try to apply it to my Data Frame it says tuple object not callable. Any ideas what is the matter?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tuple` with `Counter.most_common` like this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> tuple(Counter(('NN', 'NNP', '(', 'NN', ')')).most_common())
(('NN', 2), (')', 1), ('(', 1), ('NNP', 1))
```